# Pandas: expanding DataFrame by number of observations in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Stata has the function [expand](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/dexpand.pdf) which adds rows to a database corresponding to values in a particular column. For example:

I have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 2, 3], 
                   "B":[3,4,5]})

   A  B
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  3  5
```

What I need:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3], 
                    "B":[3,4,5, 4, 5, 5]})

   A  B
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  3  5
3  2  4
4  3  5
6  3  5
```

The value in df.loc[0,'A'] is 1, so no additional row is added to the end of the DataFrame, since B=3 is only supposed to occur once.

The value in df.loc[1,'A'] is 2, so one observation was added to the end of the DataFrame, bringing the total occurrences of B=4 to 2.

The value in df.loc[2,'A'] is 3, so two observations were added to the end of the DataFrame, bringing the total occurrences of B=5 to 3.

I've scoured prior questions for something to get me started, but no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of possibilities, all built around [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
def using_reindex(df):
    return df.reindex(np.repeat(df.index, df['A'])).reset_index(drop=True)

def using_dictcomp(df):
    return  pd.DataFrame({col:np.repeat(df[col].values, df['A'], axis=0) 
                          for col in df})

def using_df_values(df):
    return pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values, df['A'], axis=0), columns=df.columns)

def using_loc(df):
    return df.loc[np.repeat(df.index.values, df['A'])].reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

For example,

```
In [219]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 2, 3], "B":[3,4,5]})
In [220]: df.reindex(np.repeat(df.index, df['A'])).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[220]: 
   A  B
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  2  4
3  3  5
4  3  5
5  3  5
```

---

Here is a benchmark on a 1000-row
DataFrame; the result being a roughly 500K-row DataFrame:

```
In [208]: df = make_dataframe(1000)

In [210]: %timeit using_dictcomp(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 23.6 ms per loop

In [218]: %timeit using_reindex(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 35.8 ms per loop

In [211]: %timeit using_df_values(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 31.3 ms per loop

In [212]: %timeit using_loc(df)
1 loop, best of 3: 275 ms per loop
```

This is the code I used to generate `df`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def make_dataframe(nrows=100):
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'A': np.arange(nrows),
         'float': np.random.randn(nrows),
         'str': np.random.choice('Lorem ipsum dolor sit'.split(), size=nrows),
         'datetime64': pd.date_range('20000101', periods=nrows)},
        index=pd.date_range('20000101', periods=nrows))
    return df

df = make_dataframe(1000)
```

---

If there are only a few columns, `using_dictcomp` is the fastest. But note that `using_dictcomp` assumes `df` has unique column names. The dict comprehension in `using_dictcomp` won't repeat duplicated column names. The other alternatives will work with repeated column names, however.

Both `using_reindex` and `using_loc` assume `df` has a unique index.

---

`using_reindex` came from cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's `using_loc`, in an (unfortunately) now
deleted post. cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ showed it wasn't necessary to manually repeat all the values -- you only need to repeat the index and then let `df.loc` (or `df.reindex`) repeat all the rows for you. It also avoids accessing `df.values` which could generate an intermediate NumPy array of `object` dtype if `df` contains columns of multiple dtypes.

Comment: I did a benchmark out of curiosity, and your first solution is 10 times faster than mine. I know when I'm outclassed ;)